# Access JS this from Scala.js

Tags: javascript, scala, scala.js

I'm trying to convert this code from js library docs into scala.s:

```
$('#myTable').on( 'click', 'tbody td', function () {
    editor.inline( this, {
        submitOnBlur: true
    } );
} );
```

Code I tried:

```
$("#table").on("click", ".editable", (thiz: js.Dynamic) => {
  editor.inline(thiz, JC(
    submitOnBlur = true
  ))
})
```

But it gives me error:

> Cannot read property 'contents' of undefined at f.inline

Comment: What facade library do you use for jQuery? i.e., what dependency in your build/source gives you `$` to begin with?

Comment: @sjrd I have `"be.doeraene" % "scalajs-jquery_sjs0.6_2.12" % "0.9.2"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback function you wrote, i.e.,

```scala
(thiz: js.Dynamic) => {
  editor.inline(thiz, JC(
    submitOnBlur = true
  ))
}
```

is a function of 1 parameter (that happens to be called `thiz`), instead of a function that receives `this` as a parameter. In other words, it is equivalent to the following in JS:

```
function(thiz) {
  editor.inline(thiz, JC(...))
}
```

To get access to the `this`, you need to force your callback function to be a `js.ThisFunction`, as follows:

```scala
((thiz: js.Dynamic) => {
  editor.inline(thiz, JC(
    submitOnBlur = true
  ))
}): js.ThisFunction
```

This will take the first argument of the Scala lambda (in this case, the only one) and attach it to the `this` value of JavaScript, which is what you want.